# How to send an email by My Android App without showing confirmation popup?

Tags: android, email

I need some assistance please. I have Googled it but cannot seem to find an answer. I have an `Android` application, it has a process wizard that guides the user through different steps. Once all steps have been completed it needs to send a confirmation email based on the client email address saved in the local database. Getting the email address is not difficult but I have no idea how to send the email automatically without the app asking to use the `email client`.

Is there a way to do this?

This is the only code I have sofar:

```
private boolean sendEmail()
{
    boolean result = false;

    Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    emailIntent.setType("plain/text");


    return result;
}
```

Comment: There is no way to get confirmation from or sending mail in background with `Intent`. [This](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Send-Mail-in-Android-without-Using-Intent) may help .

Comment: Who should be the recipient of the email? If the answer is the user, the email should be sent by your server.

Comment: from *whom* to *whom* do you want the email to be sent?

Comment: Thank you guys, that already answered my question! I am going to send the email from the server instead! I don't know why I did not consider this. Bad day I guess!